# python code highlighting in R presentation

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, rpres

I am using RPubs to post a few multiple choice questions about Python programming.

In an .Rmd file I get Python code highlighting when valid Python code is put inside three back ticks.

I am trying to get the same highlighting in an .Rpres file (as this is how I publish to RPubs)
The code I am using is the same as in the .Rmd file